# Google Voice is not accepting Skype SMS verification messages for Caller ID, anyone got a workaround?

Tags: skype, google-voice, caller-id

I am unable to set my caller id number in Skype to my Google Voice number.  Skype's caller id verification process requires a SMS message to be sent to the requested number.  The text messages aren't getting through.

A [post on the Skype forum](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=388271) indicates that Google Voice does not support SMS messages except directly from mobile phones. Has anyone figured out a workaround to set your Google Voice number as your Skype caller id number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dial from Google voice and have it ring your skype phone.

First you will have to add you skype number to Google voice.
From Google voice hit call, enter the number you want to call, select your skype number from the drop down list and hit connect

Google voice will call your skype number and connect you with the number you called, they will see your Google voice number on their caller ID

Answer (score 0):

Gizmo was acquired by Google Voice, it will be very soon that you can use the 2 technologies together for 'free' domestic calls in the US.  If you already have a Google Voice account and Gizmo account, you can connect the 2 right now and start calling, for free.